# Let $Y,Z$ be subspaces of a Banach space $X$ such that $Y$ is isomorphic to $Z.$ Are $X/Y$ and $X/Z$ isomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The following question is taken from '[Banach Space Theory; The Basis for Linear and Nonlinear Theory](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441975140)', page $35,$ question $29.$

> **Question**: Let $Y,Z$ be subspaces of a Banach space $X$ such that $Y$ is isomorphic to $Z.$
>   Are $X/Y$ and $X/Z$ isomorphic?

Hint given states that it is no by letting $X = \ell_2, Y=\{(0,x_2,x_3,...)\}$ and $Z = \{(0,0,x_3,x_4,...)\}.$

I am trying to use the hint to solve the question. 
Let $T:Y\to Z.$
Clearly $T$ is a bounded bijection.
But I am not able to prove that $T^{-1}$ is also bounded, that is, I could not find a constant $D>0$ such that 
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty |x_k|^2\leq D \sum_{k=3}^\infty |x_k|^2.$$

Another doubt is that what is a motivation of considering the spaces given. 
In other words, how to 'see' that the question has negative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to show that $Y$ and $Z$ as defined as actually isomorphic. Intuitively that's definitely the case, $Z$ is just $Y$ with an extra zero in front of all the elements. If you wish to show this formally take $T: Y \to Z$ given by
$$ T(0, x_2, x_2, \ldots) = (0, 0, x_2, x_3, \ldots) $$
This is clearly linear, and also it's bijective since we can immediately give an inverse function $T^{-1}:Z \to Y$ where
$$ T^{-1}(0, 0, 0, x_3, x_4, \ldots) = (0, 0, x_3, x_4, \ldots) $$
It's not difficult to show in fact $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are both isometries and hence continuous.

You could appeal to the inverse function theorem to show $T^{-1}$ is continuous once you've shown $T$ is continuous by showing $Y$ and $Z$ are closed subspace of $\ell^2$ and hence Banach spaces.

Can you see why $X/Y$ and $X/Z$ are not isomorphic? (Hint: Consider dimensions)

Comment: Clearly $Y$ and $Z$ are closed subspaces as they are singleton?

Comment: Ah, in the hint $Y$ and $Z$ are not singleton points (the only singleton point that is a subspace is $\{0\}$). Rather $Y = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) \in \ell^2 : x_1 = x_2 = 0\}$ and $Z$ has a similar definition

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Comment: @Z. Xie, actually I am not completely sure what did you mean by looking at the dimensions, but it seems that I found another way to show it, but I am not completely confident.

Comment: @Z.Xie I think the part showing that $Y$ is closed is pretty straightforward. Consider a projection $P:\ell_2\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $P(x_1,x_2,...) = x_1.$ Clearly $P$ is linear and bounded (hence continuous) with $ker(P) = Y.$ Since kernel of a continuous function closed, so $Y$ is closed. $Z$ can be shown similarly.

Comment: @user284331 $X/Y \cong \mathbb{R}$, $X/Z \cong \mathbb{R}^2$. The "this is clearly invalid" part of your answer is since the two spaces you've written down have different dimensions

Comment: @Idonknow Yep, that works

Comment: @Z. Xie, yes, dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following reasoning works.

$(X/Y)^{\ast}\cong Y^{\perp}\cong \left<(1,0,...)\right>$, and $(X/Z)^{\ast}\cong Z^{\perp}\cong\left<(1,0,...),(0,1,...)\right>$. We cannot have $X/Y\cong X/Z$, if not, then $(X/Y)^{\ast}\cong(X/Z)^{\ast}$, then $\left<(1,0,...)\right>\cong\left<(1,0,...),(0,1,...)\right>$, this is clearly invalid because of the different dimensions.

Comment: I assume that $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ refers to linear span?

Comment: Yes, it is what I want to mean.